# Rails - Pass object as argument without serializing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, serialization, sidekiq

I have a controller from which I have to pass an object instance as an argument to a Worker class of Sidekiq.

My controller with the call `WegWorker.synchronize(@service)`

```
class Api::V2::Events::WegSessionsController < Api::V2::Events::ApplicationController
  before_action :load_service

  def synchronize
    @service.keep_cancelled = params[:keep_cancelled].to_b
    if @service.valid_connection?
      WegWorker.perform_async(@service)
      render json: {
        status: :ok,
        message: @service.message
      }, status: :ok
    else
      render json: {
        status: :unprocessable_entity,
        errors: @event.errors.full_messages
      }, status: :ok
    end
  end
    .. some code with service object instantiation
end
```

My worker class

```
class WegWorker < ::CarrierWave::Workers::ProcessAsset
  include Sidekiq::Worker 
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(service)

    service.synchronize
  end
end
```

But I am currently getting the error as

```
WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `synchronize' for "#<WegService:0x0000000013f9abb0>":String
```

How can I pass the object without serializing it to the worker?

Comment: What's the definition of `WegService`? How is it instantiated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sidekiq jobs can only take [simple parameters](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices), like string, number, etc. To work around this, the recommended approach is to have the following methods defined on your `WegService`:

```rb
class WegService
  def self.from_params(params)
    new(...) #rehydrate your service using params
  end

  def to_params
    [43, 'foo', 'bar'] # pickle your service
  end

  # ...
end
```

Then, you would enqueue like this:

```rb
WegWorker.perform_async(@service.to_params)
```

And the worker would have:

```rb
def perform(params)
  WebService.from_params(params).synchronize
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are queuing a complex Ruby object with this `WegWorker.perform_async(@service)`. This won't be serialized properly and you will end up with a string which looks something like this `"#<WegService:0x0000000013f9abb0>"`. While deserializing Sidekiq won't convert it into the original class like you are expecting it to.

You are supposed to queue simple objects only. So you can push identifiers to the async job and reinstantiate the service yourself inside the perform method.

Also, my advice would be to go through Sidekiq docs. They are quite small and you would save yourself from such kind of errors. [Relevant link](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple) for this section.